# GitHub Actions - Set two output names from custom action in Golang code

Tags: go, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have written a custom action in Golang, which has a function that makes two output names.

The output names are created for later use in the workflow, so I can call the action in one job ("Calculate version"), catch the output names, and use it in a different job ("Build")

The Go function inside the action to create the output name is:

```
func SetTag(value string){
    fmt.Printf(`::set-output name=repo_tag::%s`, value)
    fmt.Printf(`::set-output name=ecr_tag::%s`, "v" + value)

}
```

And the workflow that uses the said output is like so:

```
  Version:
    name: Calculate Version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      repo_version_env: ${{ steps.version.outputs.repo_tag }}
      ecr_version_env: ${{ steps.version.outputs.ecr_tag }}

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Calculate version
      id: version
      uses: my_custom_action/version@v1
  Build:
    name: Build Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build
      run: |
        echo ${{ needs.Version.outputs.ecr_version_env }}
        echo ${{ needs.Version.outputs.repo_version_env }}
```

When I run the workflow, The echo commands give me the following in the action build output:

```
1  echo 
2  echo v1.4.1::set-output name=ecr_tag::1.4.1
```

Instead of:

```
1  echo v1.4.1
2  echo 1.4.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

If there are better ways to use the variables outputted from the action, between different jobs in the workflow I will be happy to hear as well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I tested here, the problem is that the go function will print the datas like this:

`::set-output name=repo_tag::1.4.1::set-output name=ecr_tag::v1.4.1%`

And the problem seems related to the fact that you didn't break the line.

It should work by updating the Go function to:

```golang
func SetTag(value string){
    fmt.Printf(`::set-output name=repo_tag::%s`, value)
    fmt.Print("\n")
    fmt.Printf(`::set-output name=ecr_tag::%s`, "v" + value)
    fmt.Print("\n")
}
```

Note that the second `fmt.Print("\n")` will remove the `%` symbol on the terminal.

If you want to check the test I made:

- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester26.yml)
- [golang script](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/scripts/test_workflow26.go)
- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1938807087)

The output is the one you expect:

[image]